# use excel data analysis toolkit's histogram function for multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Good day all,

I have been using Excel's data analysis toolkit's histogram function to define bins and create frequency tables for small datasets. My datasets usually have had 5 -10 columns, with each row having values pertaining to the same observation. I was ok using the histogram function multiple times to manually create a frequency table for the datasets.

A screenshot of the histogram tool from excel 2016 for reference -

[image]

My datasets usually looked something like this -

```
enter code here
obs    col1    col2   col3....colN
obs1    4    2    2.5    4   N
obs2    6    7.1    4.2    6    N
obs3    6.3    2    9.5    5    N
...
obsN     N    N    N    N    N
where N is a number
```

and my output after creating bins of 0,1,2....,10,...n, manually copying and pasting the frequency distribution obtained for each column into one large datasheet to create a table like this...

```
bins   col1    col2    col3   colN
0       36      32     15      NN
1       23      54     55      NN
2       56      34     675     NN
....
N       NN      NN     NN      NN
where N is a number
```

However, I now have to deal with a very large dataset, containing over 100 columns and was wondering if there is an easier way to create a frequency table using bins for all 100 columns in one go.

I am using excel 2016.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If I'm not wrong to create Frequency only two columns can be used, 1 as Input & other is Bin,,,, either by using Analysis Tool pack or Excel Formula. In your case you need to create equal number of pairs for Input & Bin. Like 1 Bin range for more than one columns,, but it's rare to find, coz there must be logical relationship between 2 Input Columns & 1 Bin range!!